# socket programming error when server echo

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I have written a socket programming code for client as well as server side... basically when my client is entering message and my server echoes that message back ... my problem is there only... at 1st if i am entering `hieee`

```
echo: hieee
```

then if i am entering Enter msg: `it`

```
echo: it
ee <--this extra line is being print which i am not able to figure out why... :(
```

My Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h>    
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#define NTHREADS 100

void *connection_handler(void *);
pthread_t thread_id[NTHREADS];
int sockfd,d1;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;

struct msg_q {
    size_t in_index;
    size_t out_index;
    unsigned int data[2048];
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};    
// Socket create
int sock_create( )
{
    sockfd= socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

    if (sockfd <0)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");  
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Socket created");
    memset(&server,0,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 2100);
}      
// Bind
int sock_bind()
{
    int b= bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
    if (b <0)
    {
        perror("Bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Bind");

}
// Listen
int sock_listen()
{
   listen(sockfd , 10);
}
//Connection accept
int sock_accept()
{
    int s = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    d1= accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&s);

    if (d1 < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    } 
    puts("Connection accepted");
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{  int client_sock;
   sock_create();
   sock_bind();
   sock_listen();
   sock_accept();

    struct msg_q msg_queue[100];

    pthread_exit

        pthread_attr_t attr;
        int i,j;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
        printf("Creating threads\n");

    int cli_sock=client_sock;

    for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS ; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&(thread_id[i]), &attr, connection_handler, (void*) &cli_sock);
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr); //Free attribute, wait for the other threads
    for(j=0; j < NTHREADS; j++)
    {
        pthread_join( thread_id[j], NULL);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void *connection_handler(void *sfd)
{   
    int sock = d1;
    int read_size=0;
    char *message , client_message[2000];

    //Receive msg from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {   
        client_message[read_size] = '\0';
        //back to client

        write(sock, client_message , strlen(client_message));
        memset(client_message,'\0',sizeof(client_message));

    }
     if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("Recv failed");    
    }
    pthread_exit((void*) sfd);
    return 0;
}
```

My Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char msg[1000] , servaddr_reply[2000];

// Create socket
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) <0)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    servaddr.sin_family= AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port= htons(2100);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr("10.205.28.13");
 //Connect to server
    if (connect(sockfd , (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr , sizeof(servaddr)) <0)
    {
        perror("Connection failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connected");

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter msg:");
        fflush(stdout);
        bzero(msg,1000);
        scanf("%s" , msg);

        if( write(sockfd , msg , strlen(msg)) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }

        if( read(sockfd, servaddr_reply , 2000) < 0)
        {
            puts("Recv failed");
            break;
        }
        puts("Echo: ");
        puts(servaddr_reply);
        fflush(stdout);              
    }
        close (sockfd);
        return 0;
}
```

Please help as i am new to socket programming...

Comment: Out of the blue: clear out buffers before (re-)using them.

Comment: Not related to the question, but definitly to the code: Closely read the documentation for read()/write() and learn that those two functions do not necessarily read/write as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data expected had been read/written is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Comment: Also `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t` not `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read()` does not add a null terminator after the response. If you want to treat the response as a null-terminated string, you have to add it yourself:

```
int len;
if ((len = read(sockfd, servaddr_reply, sizeof(servaddr_reply)-1)) < 0) 
{
    puts("Recv failed");
    break;
}
servaddr_reply[len] = 0; // Add null terminator
puts(servaddr_reply);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: since i am using scanf so icannot enter a sentence as message... can u tell me how to handle this i thoght of using fgets() but i am having some buffer issue in that..  printf("Enter msg:");
        fflush(stdout);
        bzero(msg,1000);
        scanf("%s" , msg);

Comment: `fgets()` should work, I don't know why you would have any buffer issues with it. Sounds like you need to ask a new question about that.